# Checking whether users have a role that allows them to index sheets

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record, authorization

Is there any DRYer way to write this method ? or is it better to keep it this way for better reader understanding ...

Each role has a list of authorised activities for a specific resource ( in this case Sheet) , a user may have multiple roles ( depending upon his company, his working group in the company, his function in the working group). This method is a sheet_policy, if among all roles , the current user can "index" sheets, the method returns true otherwise it returns false

```
   def index?
    # check if sheet#index is listed in current_user roles activities
    sheet_activities = []
    user.roles.each {|role| sheet_activities << role.activities["sheet"]}
    return false if sheet_activities.first.nil? # no authorized activities on Sheet
    sheet_activities.flatten.uniq!.include?("index")
  end
```

activities is a JSONB attribute of the Sheet record ...

```
create_table :roles do |t|
  t.string      :company, null: false, default: Settings.company.default.name
  t.string      :group
  t.string      :function
  t.jsonb       :activities, null: false, default: '{}'      
  t.timestamps  null: false
```

Seeding example :

```
   @role_accounting_employee = Role.create( group: "accounting", function: "employee")  # default company : "internal"
   @role_accounting_employee.activities.deep_merge!({sheet: %w(show index) })
```

Comment: Why do you check `sheet_activities.first.nil?`? Is there anything special about the user's _first_ `role`?

Comment: the :activities field is a JSONB structure which is defaulted to an empty hash.  It can be filled dynamically later with authorised activities on different resources ( :sheet  is one of them , but not necessarily present... )
so my first test in this case is to test if any allowed activities for the :sheet resource exist... :using .each  I got a sheet.activities being [nil]
Using .map should avoid  it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Improved with `flat_map` thanks to @tokland.]

How about:

```
def index?
  user.roles.flat_map { |role| role.activities['sheet'] }.include?('index')
end
```

In Ruby, it is almost never necessary to set a temporary variable to empty and iterate over an object, given the power of methods like map, reduce, find, all?, etc. I don't see the need to use `uniq!` since it doesn't change whether index will be present or not. It's unclear why you're checking for nil on the first sheet_activities (since you can't guarantee what will be first without sorting), but if you just want to return false when sheet_activities are nil, the above will already do so.

Also note that Rubocop likes single quotes when you're not interpolating.

Comment: about first sheet_activities.nil?  see my comment above...
I also agree that .uniq! is not necessary , as I'll only check for the presence of a method (:index, ..:show..)  so I don't care for duplicated methods... I juts thought it was "pretty' :-))  
Thanks a lot ...

Comment: map + flatten(1) = flat_map